# How to display a HTTP status code of a url (For example, 404, 200, etc. ) on Spring's JSP page?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, maven, spring-mvc

I need to display a HTTP status code like 404, 200, 500, etc. of a url on a jsp page in Spring MVC. I have tried to read a lot of the online documentations but a lot of them do not show you how to exactly do it and get it displayed on a jsp page.

I have my controller like this:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)

    @ResponseBody ErrorInfo handleBadRequest(HttpServletRequest req, Exception ex) {
        return new ErrorInfo(req.getRequestURL(), ex);
    } 
}
```

And my jsp:

```
<p>The error is : ${ex} </p>
```

And also tell me what kind of Maven dependency I need in my pom.xml file.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi did you figure this out? I'm working on same project and need help.

Answer (score 0):

Return a ResponseEntity from your controller. Receive it as JSON and extract statusCode field to display it in your JSP. Alternatively you can construct a custom error response entity and return it as well. These articles will give you some idea on how to do it

http://springinpractice.com/2013/10/09/generating-json-error-object-responses-with-spring-web-mvc

http://www.journaldev.com/2651/spring-mvc-exception-handling-exceptionhandler-controlleradvice-handlerexceptionresolver-json-response-example

And for that you will need spring core and spring mvc dependencies in your classpath. Add these to your pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

In spring mvc [`@ExceptionHandler()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html) annotation is used for handling exceptions in specific handler classes and/or handler methods. You have missed this.

There are three options available to handle exceptions:

1. Per exception
2. Per controller
3. Globally

**Per exception:**

```
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason="No such Order")  // 404
public class OrderNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
   // ...
}
```

**Per Controller:**

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public ModelAndView handleError(HttpServletRequest req, Exception exception) {
    logger.error("Request: " + req.getRequestURL() + " raised " + exception);

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.addObject("exception", exception);
    mav.addObject("url", req.getRequestURL());
    mav.setViewName("error");
    return mav;
}
```

**Globally:**

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

  @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
  public ModelAndView handleError(HttpServletRequest req, Exception exception) {
    logger.error("Request: " + req.getRequestURL() + " raised " + exception);

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.addObject("exception", exception);
    mav.addObject("url", req.getRequestURL());
    mav.setViewName("error");
    return mav;
  }
}
```

> how to exactly do it and get it displayed on a jsp page.

Above globally exception handler example shows how to do that.

> And also tell me what kind of Maven dependency I need in my pom.xml
>   file.

You need to have Spring core and mvc dependencies and if you using JSON serialization and de-serialization then need to have [jackson](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core) on pom.xml

See Also:

- [Exception handling in spring mvc](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)
- [@ControllerAdive](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-controller-advice)

Comment: In the above globally exception handler, The ModelAndView mav is being returned by the method handleError, and how can I use the returned mav to get the HTTP status code to display on the jsp page?